# How to use Rserve with JSP on Tomcat? (Windows 7)

Tags: java, r, jsp, tomcat, rserve

I am trying to write a web page using JSP which can talk to R via Rserve.

I have installed R and Rserve and both are running (I have checked in task manager).

What I need to to do now is make a connection between the two. I have found examples of JAVA but not JSP. I have tried editing the JAVA code to be used as JSP but that always gives me errors relating to this bit of code:

```
        try {
        RConnection c = new RConnection();
        double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles();
        org.rosuda.REngine.REXP x0 = c.eval("R.version.string");
        System.out.println(x0.asString());
    } catch (REngineException e) {

    }
```

[I have been using the code from the answer on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216014/how-to-make-a-simple-program-to-call-r-from-java-using-eclipse-and-rserve)

I am new to both JAVA and R so I am probably missing something really simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this might help you out :)

http://www.studytrails.com/R/RServe/RServe-Java-First-Program.jsp

Comment: Thanks! Just ran it in Eclipse and it works perfect for Java! Is it possible to convert to code to JSP?

Comment: That my friend is a little to advanced for me, but I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway! I guess I'll just have to go ahead and use java instead :)

Comment: Hey Dom, if it worked out for you, do mind giving me a check mark? I'm trying to get my rep up lol :p

Comment: There you go, sorry I did try before but it said I couldn't mark it as answered yet.